# Instructing Sping Data MongoDB to use correct mapping between ObjectId and its class

Tags: spring, mongodb, mapstruct, objectid

I cannot retrieve the 2nd level nested objects in Spring Data MongoDB

I have nested collection in MongoDB to retrieve with Spring. Imagine this schema

```
@Data
@Builder
@Document(collection = "emitted")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Emitter{

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field("installation")
    @DocumentReference(lazy = true)
    private Installaton installation;

    // other fields
```

```
@Data
@Builder
@Document(collection = "installation")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Installation {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field("subject")
    @DocumentReference(lazy = true)
    private Subject subject;
    
    // other fields
```

```
@Data
@Builder
@Document(collection = "subject")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Subject {

    @Id
    private String id;

    // other fields
```

Plus, I have MapStruct to map nested object field to string, for the purpose of avoiding cyclic reference introducing the search by id of the collection:

```
@ObjectFactory
public <T> T map(@NonNull final String id, @TargetType Class<T> type) {
    return mongoTemplate.findById(id, type);
}
```

Everything works at first level, but at nested level I have this error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.bson.types.ObjectId] to type [com.package.collections.Subject]
> at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:322)
> at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:195)
> at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:175)
> at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.doConvert(MappingMongoConverter.java:1826)
> at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.doConvert(MappingMongoConverter.java:1818)
> at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.getPotentiallyConvertedSimpleRead(MappingMongoConverter.java:1337)
> at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.getPotentiallyConvertedSimpleRead(MappingMongoConverter.java:1311)
> at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$DefaultConversionContext.convert(MappingMongoConverter.java:2371)
> at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$ConversionContext.convert(MappingMongoConverter.java:2174)
> at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1936)
> at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readProperties(MappingMongoConverter.java:638)
> at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.populateProperties(MappingMongoConverter.java:549)
> at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:527)
> at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readDocument(MappingMongoConverter.java:491)
> at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:427)
> at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:423)
> at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:120)
> at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$ReadDocumentCallback.doWith(MongoTemplate.java:3326)
> at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindOneInternal(MongoTemplate.java:2940)
> at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFindOne(MongoTemplate.java:2618)
> at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFindOne(MongoTemplate.java:2588)
> at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.findById(MongoTemplate.java:922)
> at com.package.myapp.services.mapper.ReferenceMapper.map(ReferenceMapper.java:26)
> at com.package.myapp.services.mapper.InstallationMapperImpl.toEntity(InstallationMapperImpl.java:102)

When asking the conversion, the findById works correctly and retrieve the object and the nested one. It fails when the request is for 2nd level nested object, where the ObjectId is retrieved but cannot be converted and fails.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering myself because I found a solution suited for my problem.

I only needed the entity object with the id, so I wrote a converter:

```
public class ObjectIdToSubjectConverter implements Converter<ObjectId, Subject> {
    @Override
    public Subject convert(ObjectId source) {
        return Subject.builder().id(source.toString()).build();
    }
}
```

And register it as a bean:

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfig {
    @Bean
    public MongoCustomConversions mongoCustomConversions() {
        return new MongoCustomConversions(Collections.singletonList(new ObjectIdToSubjectConverter());
    }
}
```